# Getting a clash on casting using Xamarin Preferences

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am getting a strange issue with xamarin [essentials preferences documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?tabs=android) I am getting a time out the issue at present.

```
var warehouseFromId =  Preferences.Get("WarehouseFromId", "");
WarehouseFromId = Convert.ToInt64(warehouseFromId);
```

I am setting the value as such using a constructor method called savedSettings but sometimes that won't be called till the user has clicked a button, so why is my getting a cast exception.

```
public string WarehouseFromName { get; set; }
public long WarehouseFromId { get; set; }

warehouseFromName="TT";
WarehouseFromId=1839;

Preferences.Set("WarehouseFrom", warehouseFromName);
Preferences.Set("WarehouseFromId", WarehouseFromId);
```

So I thought may have been because I am using "" which would denote a string so i tried the following.

```
var warehouseFromId =  Preferences.Get("WarehouseFromId", 0);
```

I got the bellow

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> Java.Lang.ClassCastException:   then i got this after my test above

Unhandled Exception:

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: int
>   Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences.Get(string,int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, you could need to take a care Convert.ToInt64(), Converts a specified value to a 64-bit signed integer, it is not a empty or null.

Preferences.Get() is to retrieve a value from preferences or a default if not set, so If you want to use Preferences.Get() to set vakue firstly, then retrive this value, please confirm you don't use Preferences.Set("my_key", "my_value") to set value before, otherwise it will report a error.

```
 public string WarehouseFromName { get; set; }
    public long WarehouseFromId { get; set; }
    public long Id { get; set; }

 Preferences.Clear();
        WarehouseFromName = "TT";
        WarehouseFromId = 1839;

        Preferences.Set("WarehouseFrom", WarehouseFromName);
        Preferences.Set("WarehouseFromId", WarehouseFromId);
        Console.WriteLine("the WarehouseFromId is {0}",Convert.ToInt64(WarehouseFromId));
       Id= Preferences.Get("Id", 0);
        Console.WriteLine("the value is {0}",Convert.ToInt64(Id));
```